# selenium webdriver no element found error in internet explorer

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting below error in `Internet explorer 8` but working same in `Firefox` (Both name, xpath are same)

```
"Unable to find element with name == username (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"
```

My HTML Looks like

```
<class=form>User Name 

<INPUT tabIndex=0 size=22 name=username autocomplete="off"\>

class=form>Password

<INPUT tabIndex=0 onkeypress="checkCapsLock( event )" value="" size=22 type=password name=password autocomplete="off\>
```

My JAVA Code :

```
File file = new File("D:/vishwas/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe");    
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());    
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();    
driver.get("http://10.26.210.74:9080/cbaUserAdmin/");    
WebElement Name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']"));    
Name.sendKeys(new String[]{"username"});    
WebElement Pass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"));    
Pass.sendKeys(new String[]{"password"});
```

Full HTML Code of this Page:

```
<table bgcolor="#ffffd0" cellPadding="1" cellSpacing="1" border=0 >

            <tr>
                <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="65%">&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <FONT SIZE="3"><B>Log on</B></FONT>
                </td>           
                <td>&nbsp;</td>                     
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan=4>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="form">User Name</td>
                <td class="form">
                    <input type="text" tabindex="0" size="22" name="username" autocomplete="off" />
                </td>           
                <td>&nbsp;</td>                     
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>             
                <td class="form">Password</td>
                <td class="form">
                    <input type="password" tabindex="0" name="password" size="22" autocomplete="off" onKeyPress="checkCapsLock( event )"/>
                    <!--<span id="spanCaps" class="PopupBox" style="margin-left:10;vertical-align:bottom;">Caps Lock is <b>ON</b></span>-->
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>                 
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="form" >
                    <span id="spanCaps" class="PopupBox">Caps Lock is <b>ON</b></span>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" tabindex="0" value="Login">
```

Please help me with this as I wonder why am I getting in `Internet explorer` particularly..

Thanks,
Vishwas

Comment: Provide the actual HTML please. What you have provided is not HTML at all.

Comment: @Arran ... Two text boxes are there "username" and "password".  I want to enter strings in those text boxes. I am getting error that element with that name or xpath is not found in Internet explorer.. 

PS : It is working in firefox.

Comment: What version of Firefox? What version of Selenium? What version of the IE Driver? What OS?

Comment: Cofiguration are..Firefox v14, Webdriver 2.28, IEDriver 2.28, Windows XP 32 bit

Comment: @Arran        
I updated my question with full HTML code. Could you please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way IE handles xpath expressions is different from that of FF. Try to use CSS.

The Exception says driver is not able to identify the element with name.

First try to identify the table.

Then try to identify the row

then try to identify the td

then try to identify the input element and perform action on it.

If there is a table, the row is 3rd row and td is the 5th one, I would write something like this.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table tr+tr+tr td+td+td+td+td input")).sendkeys("xxxx");
```

Comment: Could you please explain because i dont how do i perform using find element by CSS selector..

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please take a look into it. Hope it helps.

Comment: I Tried the way you mentioned above but i am getting same error :(

Comment: Is there frame in your html?

Comment: And another thing is your question is very simple to resolve but you may be not presenting your question in constructive way. I've tested your html and my answer works and the other guy answer works too.

Comment: I gave absolute path like :
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/input")).sendKeys(new String[]{"xxx"});

It worked! For everytime do i need to give absolute path? thanks for your help

Comment: If my help is of use to you, you can accept my answer by clicking the tick mark. You don't need to give absolute path,  in this case, you can start the path from the table. If you've a frame, first you need to switch to the frame and find elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

You specified the tag in the Code with the name "username" and you want to access it with the xPath "User Name".

Try

```
WebElement Name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']"));
```

instead.

Comment: I tried WebElement Name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")); and 
driver.findElement(By.name("username]")) but both dint worked showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is a bit messed up in the question, but it looks like the input is named "username" and your xpath is looking for "User Name"

You can check your HTML validity using the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/).
Browsers will try to work with invalid HTML by making some assumptions about the structure, and it may be that is happening and causing your xpath to not match.

Perhaps your HTML should look something like:

```
<form>
  User Name <input tabIndex="0" size="22" name="username" autocomplete="off">

  Password  <input tabindex="0" onkeypress="checkCapsLock( event )" value="" size="22" type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

As an alternative, you could lookup the fields with css:

```
WebElement Name = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=username]"));
Name.sendKeys(new String[]{"username"});        
WebElement Pass = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=password]"));    
Pass.sendKeys(new String[]{"password"});
```

or by name

```
WebElement Name = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
Name.sendKeys(new String[]{"username"});        
WebElement Pass = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));    
Pass.sendKeys(new String[]{"password"});
```

Comment: I tried WebElement Name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")); and driver.findElement(By.name("username]")) but both dint worked showing the same error

Comment: I've updated the answer to address some potential HTML structure issues and included a link to the w3c html validator

Comment: I have tested with selenium 2.28.0, IE8 on Windows 7 and it works with the HTML you provided.  I have uploaded the [HTML/java code I used into this gist](https://gist.github.com/4593464) .  The gist also shows selecting the elements by css/name working.  I did need to make the protected mode settings changes described on the [InternetExplorerDriver page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was getting this error because in internet explorer i was giving relative Xpath...Now i gave absolute xpath.. It worked Thanks a lot for all who spend their time to help me..